# AngularFire2 authentication; no callback credentials for Google and Twitter (Facebook works fine!)

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I am having problems getting social login credentials when use AngularFire2 for my authentication in my Ionic2 App, the product versions I am using are:

> angular: 2.0.0
>
> firebase: 3.5.2
>
> angularfire2: 2.0.0-beta.5
>
> ionic-angular: 2.0.0-rc.1

---

### My situation

I am declaring my Firebase credentials and initializing AngularFire2 in my "**app.module.ts**"

```
import { FirebaseServiceAuth } from '../providers/firebase-service-auth';

export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: " … ",
  authDomain: " … ",
  databaseURL: " … ",
  storageBucket: " … ",
  messagingSenderId: " … "
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    …
  ],
  imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    …
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    …
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    …
  ],
  providers: [
    FirebaseServiceAuth
  ]
})
```

Then utilizing an auth provider so that it can be called globally.

Within my “**firebase-service-auth.ts**” I have 3 services each calling a different social authentication method:

```
@Injectable()
export class FirebaseServiceAuth {
  …
  constructor(private af: AngularFire, … ) {}
  …

  loginWithFacebook() {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      this.af.auth.login({
        provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
        method: AuthMethods.Popup
      }).then((success) => {
        console.log('facebook success: ', success);
        observer.next();
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.info("error", error);
        observer.error(error);
      });
    });
  }

  loginWithGoogle() {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      this.af.auth.login({
        provider: AuthProviders.Google,
        method: AuthMethods.Popup
      }).then((success) => {
        console.log('google success: ', success);
        observer.next();
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.info("error", error);
        observer.error(error);
      });
    });
  }

  loginWithTwitter() {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      this.af.auth.login({
        provider: AuthProviders.Twitter,
        method: AuthMethods.Popup
      }).then((success) => {
        console.log('twitter success: ', success);
        observer.next();
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.info("error", error);
        observer.error(error);
      });
    });
  } 
}
```

### My problem

When I call "**loginWithFacebook()**" I get the following console output:

```
> facebook success: Object {auth: W, uid: “XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX”, provider: 2, facebook: Lf}
```

However when I call “**loginWithGoogle()**” or “**loginWithTwitter()**” I get this:

```
> google success: undefined
```

or

```
> twitter success: undefined
```

### My question

Because I am wanting to create an entry in my firebase db for each user (which works fine for facebook as so)

```
console.log('facebook success: ', success);
  this.af.database.list('users').update(success.auth.uid, {
    name: success.auth.displayName,
    email: success.auth.email,
    provider: '[social provider]',
    avatar: success.auth.photoURL
  });
observer.next();
```

How do I achieve the same credential callback for Google and Twitter?